# How to apply ResourceDirectory to Window?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I am trying to create a custom WPF window using the codeproject article. I have simply created a resource file but I am struggling to apply this Resource Directory to WPF window to apply visual style.

Resource directory is fine but my MainWindow.xaml need to update code to apply this Resource directory. I am sending Resource directory and my MainWindow.xaml code.  Please anyone help and update main MainWindow.xaml to get the desired results.

Following is the Resource Directory code.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"> 
    <Style x:Key="MainWindow" 
           TargetType="{x:Type Window}"> 
        <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}" /> 
        <Setter Property="Template"> 
            <Setter.Value> 
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}"> 
                    <Grid> 
                        <Border x:Name="MainBorder" 
                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MainWindowBorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="1" 
                                CornerRadius="2" 
                                Background="{DynamicResource MainWindowBackgroundBrush}"> 
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True"> 
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_LEFT_BORDER" 
                                           Width="2" 
                                           Cursor="SizeWE"> 
                                    <Rectangle.Fill> 
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" /> 
                                    </Rectangle.Fill> 
                                </Rectangle> 
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_RIGHT_BORDER" 
                                           Cursor="SizeWE" 
                                           Width="2" 
                                           DockPanel.Dock="Right"> 
                                    <Rectangle.Fill> 
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" /> 
                                    </Rectangle.Fill> 
                                </Rectangle> 
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_TOP_BORDER" 
                                           Cursor="SizeNS" 
                                           DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                                           Height="2"> 
                                    <Rectangle.Fill> 
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" /> 
                                    </Rectangle.Fill> 
                                </Rectangle> 
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_BOTTOM_BORDER" 
                                           Cursor="SizeNS" 
                                           Height="2" 
                                           DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"> 
                                    <Rectangle.Fill> 
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" /> 
                                    </Rectangle.Fill> 
                                </Rectangle> 
                                <Border x:Name="PART_TITLEBAR" 
                                        Margin="2,0,2,2" 
                                        Height="40" 
                                        DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                                        CornerRadius="2" 
                                        Background="Transparent"> 
                                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False"> 
                                        <TextBlock Margin="8,0,0,4" 
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                   FontStretch="UltraExpanded" 
                                                   Foreground="Black" 
                                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
                                                   TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" 
                                                   FontSize="16" /> 
                                        <Button x:Name="PART_CLOSE" 
                                                DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                                                Style="{DynamicResource FlatButton}" 
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                Margin="0,0,4,0"> 
                                            <Image Source="/MixModes.Synergy.Resources;
                        component/Resources/Close.png" 
                                                   Stretch="None" 
                                                   Margin="4" /> 
                                        </Button> 
                                        <Button x:Name="PART_MAXIMIZE_RESTORE" 
                                                DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                Style="{DynamicResource FlatButton}"> 
                                            <Image x:Name="MaximizeRestoreImage" 
                                                   Source="/MixModes.Synergy.Resources;
                        component/Resources/Restore.png" 
                                                   Stretch="None" 
                                                   Margin="4" /> 
                                        </Button> 
                                        <Button x:Name="PART_MINIMIZE" 
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                Style="{DynamicResource FlatButton}" 
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                DockPanel.Dock="Right"> 
                                            <Image Margin="4" 
                                                   Source="/MixModes.Synergy.
                        Resources;component/Resources/
                        Minimize.png" 
                                                   Stretch="None" /> 
                                        </Button> 
                                    </DockPanel> 
                                </Border>

                                <!-- Title bar separator--> 
                                <Border Height="1" 
                                        DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                                        Background="{DynamicResource 
                    MainWindowTitleBarSeparator}" />

                                <!-- Actual Window Content --> 
                                <AdornerDecorator DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"> 
                                    <ContentPresenter /> 
                                </AdornerDecorator> 
                            </DockPanel> 
                        </Border> 
                    </Grid> 
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                        
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource Self}, Path=Maximized}" 
                                     Value="False"> 
                            <Setter TargetName="MaximizeRestoreImage" 
                                    Property="Source" 
                                    Value="/MixModes.Synergy.Resources;
                component/Resources/Maximize.png" /> 
                        </DataTrigger> 
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
                </ControlTemplate> 
            </Setter.Value> 
        </Setter> 
    </Style> 
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And now my MainWindow.xaml window where i need to apply Resource Directory above.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Wpf_Parent_Stype
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the article link which i am trying to implement.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140267/Create-Custom-Windows-in-WPF-with-Ease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the `TargetType` property of `Style` and using Setter to set the Template property, the specified template is applied automatically to all elements of that type. However, the style should be located at file `App.xaml`. If you locate your style at a `Window`, then style just applies just to the `Window` where you put the style. The syntax is:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
```

**OR:**

To apply the style to a control we set the Style property to our style. To get it from the resources we use the {StaticResource [resourceKey]} markup extension.

```
<Window>
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="yourStyle" TargetType="Button">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
       <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
       <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4" />
       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource yourStyle}">Express</Button>
    <Button >yourself</Button>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource yourStyle}">by Style</Button>
</StackPanel>
```